# Error while running least common subsequence program

Tags: python

There is an error at `lcw[r][len(v)+1]=0` function is not subscrptable.

```
def  lcw(u,v):
    for r in range(len(u)+1):
        lcw[r][len(v)+1]=0
    for c in range(len(v)+1):
        lcw[len(u)+1][c]=0
    maxlcw=0
    for c in range(len(v)+1,-1,-1):
        for r in range(len(u)+1,-1,-1):
            if u[r]==v[c]:
                lcw[r][c]=1+lcw[r+1][c+1]
            else:
                lcw[r][c]=0
            if  lcw[r][c]>maxlcw:
                maxlcw=lcw[r][c]
     return(maxlcw)
lcw(['fgshf'],['vdbhf'])
```

Comment: show us,  some error, what is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `lcw` to both the name of the function and some other value that's not present in your script.